# Evaluating $\int\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{1+x^2}\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration

Can anyone shed some light on evaluating the following integral? 
$$\int\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx$$

Substitution $u = x^6$ does not get me any further or is it just my algebra?

Comment: Why $x^6$ and not $x^3$ ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: with $x^2=u^3$ you get $2x\,\mbox{d}x=3u^2\,\mbox{d}u$ so $x^{1/3}\,\mbox{d}x=\tfrac{3}{2}u\,\mbox{d}u$ and the integral becomes:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{1+x^2}\,\mbox{d}x=\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{u}{1+u^3}\,\mbox{d}u$$
Continuing with partial fractions may be a bit tedious, but it is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

**Another Hint**: Take $$u=x^{1/3}$$ then, 
$$du= \frac{1}{3x^{2/3}}dx$$
hence the integral would be 
$$3\int\frac{u^3}{u^6+1}du$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
& u = \sqrt[3] x \\
& u^3 = x \\
& 3u^2\,du = dx \\  \\
& \int \frac{\sqrt[3]x}{1+x^2} \, dx = \int\frac u {1+u^6} 3u^2 \, du
\end{align}
$$
1+u^6 = (u^2+1)(u^2-u\sqrt 3 + 1)(u^2+u\sqrt 3 + 1)
$$
All three of these quadratic polynomials are irreducible unless one brings in complex numbers, as can be seen by completing the square or by looking at their discriminants.

Partial fractions should do the rest. I suspect there are also some really slick ways to do this even without resorting to thinking about residues, etc.

Comment: I think I am just a bit rusty on my factorisation ! Interestingly enough I too went seeking a solution via residues. However, the exponent of x (1/3) in the denominator, seems to be outside of the range of standard approach(as n - 1 = 1/3 => n = 4/3, > 1). Care to comment on use of complex variables in this case ?

Comment: Note that if $u^6=-1,$ then $u = \cos\alpha + i\sin\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ for which $6\alpha\equiv\pi\bmod2\pi.$ Thus $\alpha\equiv \pm\pi/6$ or $\pm\pi/2$ or $\pm5\pi/6.$ With $\pm\pi/6$ we get the factor $\Big(u - \cos(\pi/6)\pm i\sin(\pi/6)\Big),$ and so you have $$ \left( u - \frac{\sqrt3}2 - i\frac12\right) \left( u - \frac{\sqrt3}2 + i\frac 1 2\right) = u^2 - u\sqrt 3 + 1, $$ and similarly for the other factors. That is how I did this factorization. $\qquad$